# Excel VBA, offset two arrays and sum them up

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, match

I was writing my first VBA code to sum two arrays from an excel worksheet with a large amount of data, but I could not figure out a way to do it.

This is the code I wrote:

```
Sub sumTriangles()
    Dim x As Variant, y As Variant
    Dim MatchX As Long, MatchY As Long

    MatchX = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Output").Range("D4").Value, Sheets("data").Range("A:A"), 0) + 1     
    'I have two worksheets "Output" and "data". In "data", it's all data with a unique reference number for each row in column A (thousands of rows). In "Output", I have the reference number in cell D4, so I used a match function to find where the reference number is in the data sheet.   

    x = Sheets("data").Range("A1").Offset(MatchX, 3)
    'I was trying to use an offset function, and take an array of size 42*192, and assign it to x, then I can sum x and y. Apparently, the offset function in worksheet and vba are very different, and vba offset does not return to an array

    MatchY = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("Output").Range("D5").Value, Sheets("data").Range("A:A"), 0) + 1
    y = Sheets("data").Range("A1").Offset(MatchY, 3)

    Range("Sum") = x + y 'sum the two arrays
End Sub
```

I was wondering if there is a way to solve this problem, or do I have to write a function to imitate a workbook offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheets("data").Range("A1").Offset(MatchX, 3)` starts with a range with a single cell and offsets this cell, giving a range with a single cell.

`Sheets("data").Range("A1:P192").Offset(MatchX, 3)` starts with a range of 42*192 cells and offsets this, giving a range of 42*192 cells.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying it now